# Windows batch script issue FOR loop using variable that has wild characters

Tags: batch-file

I have a for loop issue in a windows batch script that is stumping me for the moment.
The following is a simplified example of the problem code:

```
set dellist=blah.txt,BIN\debug_*.exe,BIN\test.txt,driv\??PE

for %%a in (%dellist%) do (  
    echo deleting %%a  
    rem other code  
    )
```

When executing this any value in dellist that contains a wildchar <* or ?> is not processed in the "do ( )" section.

output generated is:

```
deleting blah.txt  
deleting BIN\test.txt
```

Ive played with EnabledDelayedExpansion, using a for /f "delims=,", changing the set to use spaces instead of ,

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, but remember to read the ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) policy article, and [edit] your post to use the [proper markdown](/markdown) for code vs plain text.

Comment: `for` expands wildcard masks to matching file names (try with `*.txt`). If there are no matching files, you get nothing. That's hard-coded behaviour you can't change.

Comment: to be more precise: `for` processes file sets, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue.  In summary, paths matter with wild characters in use.  In my batch when this code was executing the script was 2 directories below where the string of folders in %dellist% exists.  The script can find the specific files listed without the full path but when a wildchar is in use it was not finding them.  Simplified solution was to add a cd to the script prior to the if statement to be in the directory where those paths work.  Here's the code change:

```
cd sql\compiled
set dellist=blah.txt,BIN\debug_*.exe,BIN\test.txt,driv\??PE

for %%a in (%dellist%) do (  
  echo deleting %%a  
  del /f "%PKGDIR%\SQL\compiled\%%a"   
  )
cd %PKGDIR%
```